# How to get two or more commands together into a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, vbscript

I want to enter a command in command prompt after reaching a specific location. How can I achieve this?

e.g.,

```
set PathName="X:\Web Content Mgmt\Completed Filtering\2013_Folder"
set comd="dir /b /s *.zip"
start "cmd" cd /d %PathName%
```

I am opening the command prompt and giving it a path using `PathName`.  Now after reaching that specific path I want to insert the `comd` variable into the command prompt to get the desired result.

These are the specific commands I am trying to execute in the batch file:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
C:\Users\anoopn>x:
X:\>cd
X:\Web Content Mgmt\Completed Filtering\2013_Folder
X:\Web Content Mgmt\Completed Filtering\2013_Folder> dir /b /s *.zip > C:\Users\anoopn\Desktop\abc.csv
```

Answer (score 35):

To get a user Input  :

```
set /p pathName=Enter The Value:%=%
@echo %pathName%
```

[image]

p.s. this is also valid :

`set /p pathName=Enter The Value:`

Comment: I want to append the user input with the path which I give as an input to the command prompt and execute that command then fetch the appropriate result and store that result in a .CSV file.

Comment: Tha's what ive done. look again. you can do anything with the %pathName% var

Comment: I have to enter two path and 1st i have to reach to X drive and the exact location, then I have to run another script that means I have to perform two actions 1st action I acheived by using set PathName="X:\Web Content Mgmt\Completed Filtering\2013_Folder"
start "cmd" cd /d %x%
Still i need to perform another action and then work on it so kindly suggest me a perfect alternative

Comment: @Anoop you're very unclear. please simplify your question . you have 2 scripts and you want both of them to know the %pathName% ?

Comment: What I am exactly trying to acheive is to build a .bat file for the script

Comment: My command prompt shows below given details:
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\anoopn>x:

X:\>cd X:\Web Content Mgmt\Completed Filtering\2013_Folder

X:\Web Content Mgmt\Completed Filtering\2013_Folder>dir /b /s *.zip > C:\Users\anoopn\Desktop\abc.csv


I want a batch file that executes the above commands

Comment: What is that %=%? a typo? When i do set /p=Enter the value:%=% I get C:\\>Enter The Value:%=%myvalue    i.e. the %=% comes up as literal after the text of my prompt

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following command. The `SET` will set the input from the user console to the variable **comment** and then you can use that variable using **%comment%**

```
SET /P comment=Comment: 
echo %comment%
pause
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: **edited**

```
@echo off
set "comd=dir /b /s *.zip"
set "pathName="
set /p "pathName=Enter The Value: "
cd /d "%pathName%"
%comd%
pause
```

Comment: Still its not working for me. Hope to get a perfect answer from your end.

Comment: I had a misplaced quote - try it now.

Comment: My reply answers your question, right?  If you have another question then open a new question.  That's how stack overflow works, I think.

Comment: that works only from second time when set X is saved in env variable

Comment: Why does it work from the second time?  What is `X`? If you have wrapped it in a loop then it needs delayed expansion and syntax changes, because that is how loops work.

Answer (score 2):

```
set "PathName=X:\Web Content Mgmt\Completed Filtering\2013_Folder"
set "comd=dir /b /s *.zip"
cd /d "%PathName%"
%comd%
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you right (not sure), the `start` parameter /D should help you:

```
start "cmd" /D %PathName% %comd%
```

/D sets the start-directory
(see start /?)

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating other batch files from your outputs then put a line like this in your batch file

```
echo %pathname%\foo.exe >part2.txt
```

then you can have your defined `part1.txt` and `part3.txt` already done and have your batch

```
copy part1.txt + part2.txt +part3.txt thebatyouwanted.bat
```