# Run script with typing parameter from bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

for example i want to run below script from bat file and that working

```
cd myproject\java myapp.java
```

but i want change `myapp.java` by typing

I try to make a bat file `mybat.bat` that i can typing `mayapp.java` from cmd

How to do that thanks

## Update

I try below but not working

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P uname=Please enter name: 
setlocal
CD myproject\java %uname%
%comd%
pause
endlocal
```

Comment: [Get user Input in command prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524332/get-user-input-in-command-prompt)

Comment: CD myproject\java %uname%  what is this supposed to do? Type cd /?. As written if a user enters fred it will change to a folder relative to the current folder called "myproject\java fred". What is %comd% supposed to do and If you've set it outsidethe program what is it's value. Why do you have echo off thus hiding all attempts by windows to tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the user input in an environment variable using the following command :

```
set /p env_var=prompt
```

But to be safer, protect your parent environmenent using :

```
setlocal
:your commands...
endlocal
```

Comment: are you sure the comd is well defined in parent environment? and what is the purpose of the CD line? only a dir change or are you trying to run a java app at the same time? btw setlocal has to be called before set /p to be useful but that is not the cause of your problem

Answer (score 0):

This should change the working directory to a folder on your desktop called `myproject` and then launch `java` with what you have typed.

Java may need the full path to the executable if the error message tells you that java is not a valid name.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P uname=Please enter name: 
CD /d "%userprofile%\desktop\myproject"
java %uname%
pause
```