# How to use "If" in BATCH

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement

i'm stuck at something in a BATCH script.

So what i want to do is execute a specific action, defined by the user input. Like, if i press M, the BATCH script executes the command 'goto menu" and if i press X, it executes "goto shutdown"

Here's a template of what i want to do:

```
:boot
@echo off
color 17
title [title]
cls
:main menu
echo I-----------------------------I
echo I         SOVIET OS           I
echo I-----------------------------I
echo I                             I
echo I press X to exit             I
echo I                             I
echo I-----------------------------I
```

following this code, i try to do something like this

```
if (%userinput% = X) then (goto shutdown)
```

the :shutdown looks like this:

```
:shutdown
echo Thanks you for using SovietOS! Shall the vodka be with you!
timeout 1 >nul
```

[the lack of command actually closes the window]

Comment: Duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223721/in-windows-cmd-how-do-i-prompt-for-user-input-and-use-the-result-in-another-com, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524332/get-user-input-in-command-prompt, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879791/how-to-read-input-from-console-in-a-batch-file.

Comment: @KerrekSB The questions you linked are for how to get user input for the batch file. I believe this person is wondering of the IF...THEN structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (%userinput% == X) goto :setup
```

Here is a site that discusses IF...THEN, IF...THEN...ELSE, and GOTO

http://commandwindows.com/batchfiles-branching.htm

Comment: `if %userinput%==X goto :setup`

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this i make so if you press x then enter it closes the program
and if you press 1 you goto main menu hope this will help you

code here

```
@echo off
color 17
title [title]
cls
:mainmenu
echo I-----------------------------I
echo I         SOVIET OS           I
echo I-----------------------------I
echo I press 1 to goto menu        I
echo I press X to exit             I
echo I                             I
echo I-----------------------------I
set /P SOVIET=? 
if %SOVIET% EQU 1 goto menu
if %SOVIET% EQU x goto exit
goto mainmenu
:exit
exit
:menu
::here you can make your menu 
pause
```